# Return value from saga to react component

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-saga

I am new at ReactJS. Still wrapping my head around all the layers with redux-store and sagas and etc.
I am trying to return a simple boolean value from a saga (which at this point the saga is returning correctly) to a react component.

Here is what I have:

On the container component I have this:

```
export interface IKpaPickerConnectedDispatch {
    lookupListDialogToggle?: (dialogProps: ILookupListDialog) => void;
    requestSaveProfileFieldItem?: (profieFieldItem: IProfileFieldItem) => void;
    // setKpiPercentageShow?: (value: boolean) => void;
    updateKpaKpiProfilePercentage?: (toggle: boolean, jobId: number) => void;
    getKpaKpiProfilePercentageToggle?: (jobId: number) => void;
}

function mapStateToProps(state: IGlobalApplicationState, ownProps: IKpaPickerProps): IKpaPickerConnectedState {
    return {
        kpiPercentageShow: actions.requestKpaKpiToggle(state.jobProfileState.jobProfile!.id)
    };
}
```

On the saga side I have this:

```
function* requestKpaKpiToggle(action: IKpaKpiToggleReceive)
{
    try {
        const  jobId = action.payload!;
        const REQUEST_URL = `${REMPROFILE_API_URL}/KpaKpi/GetKpaKpiJobProfilePercentageToggle/${jobId}`;
        const response = yield fetch(REQUEST_URL, secureHeader('GET'));
        const json = yield response.json();
        // new method to return value and update state
        yield put(requestKpaKpiToggleReceived(json));
    }
    catch (e) {
        yield put(logError(e));
    }
}
```

I get the following error and don't quite understand why :-(
Type 'Action' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.

Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**

Ok after input I have manage to get 1 step closer but not there yet.

I added this in the reducer for state management

```
case ActionKeys.KPA_KPI_TOGGLE_RECEIVE: {
    global.console.log('KPA_KPI_TOGGLE_RECEIVE', action.payload);
    return state.set('isKpiPercentageShown', action.payload)
                .set('kpiPercentageReceived', true) as JobProfileState;
}
```

Problem now is it doesn't update

```
componentDidMount()
{
    if(this.props.getKpaKpiProfilePercentageToggle && !this.state.kpiPercentageReceived)
        this.props.getKpaKpiProfilePercentageToggle(this.props.jobId);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its seems like your error comes from the following line:

```
kpiPercentageShow: actions.requestKpaKpiToggle(state.jobProfileState.jobProfile!.id)
```

Because you have used TypeScript to identify `kpiPercentageShow` as a `bool` in the Interface of `IKpaPickerConnectedDispatch`.

Moreover, you are trying to get the value from your action directly which is impossible. Inspect your flow, the `boolean` value shouldn't come from your actions. It should be available to you in `mapStateToProps` after you updated your store with a reducer.

Comment: Thanks, I edited my question. Hope you can assist where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You should put another action when the saga completes, an action that the relevant reducer catches, with your boolean.

You could have 2 actions:

REQUEST: handled by the saga (you already do that).
REQUEST_HANDLED: dispatched by the saga, handled by a reducer.

In your saga:

yield put({type: REQEUEST_HANDLED, result: true|false});

In your reducer:

case REQUEST_HANDLED:
return {...state, someFlag: someValue};

This is an example of what you could do. As I don't know exactly why you want to return a boolean and return response.json() instead.

The pattern I often use with redux-saga is have an action dispatched by a component, which is handled by a saga. When the saga is done, it dispatches an action that is handled by a reducer that changes the state in the store accordingly, telling the component the job is done.

Also, I usually have a 3rd action, which is used by the saga in the catch block, in case of an error, so the component is informed and can display a message to the user (or take any other appropriate action on error).

Comment: Can you perhaps give me an example of this please or point me to something? Like I said I don't understand everything yet so I learn as I go along

Comment: Thanks for your update. I also updated my question if you perhaps can assist